# Is the word "force" ever used in a Star Wars film dialog to mean not "THE Force"?

Tags: star-wars

As far as I can think, I think the only way the word "force" is used in SW movies is to mean "THE Force".  I don't recall it ever being used to mean "to force someone to do something" or "a military force" or "the force of the thrusters" or those kinds of meanings of the term.  Was it ever accidentally used to mean just the regular old English meanings of the word?

Comment: I see a fair number of downvotes, always curious why if you care to explain : )

Comment: Probably down to a lack of research put in. It's trivial to find the scripts and the answers below took mere seconds to locate.

Comment: @Richard that makes sense

Comment: I'm much more curious why this has 15 upvotes!

Comment: ANH is a beautiful feat of scriptwriting. All instances of "force" refer to the Force either directly or indirectly. Thanks for asking this question. I never realised how the writers avoid using the generic word "force"!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ever? Yes, quite a few times.

Here's one from *The Phantom Menace*:

> NUTE GUNRAY and DAULTRAY DOFINE stand, stunned, before TC-14.
>
> NUTE : (shaken) What?!? What did you say?
>
> TC-14 : The Ambassadors are Jedi Knights, I believe.
>
> DOFINE : I knew it! They were sent to **force** a settlement, eh. Blind me,
> we're done for!

Emphasis added.

You can find other uses in the scripts:

1. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html
2. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html
3. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Revenge-of-the-Sith.html
4. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html
5. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html
6. http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html

Comment: FWIW - I did not find a spoken example of the specific requested usage in the Empire Strikes Back script, and as Richard points out, the only non 'Force' use in New Hope is by Solo.

Comment: "An overwhelming force of force users that force the force to force the other force users to force the force over to the dark side with the force."

Answer (score 28):

"A small Rebel force has penetrated the shield and landed on Endor." - Vader, Return of the Jedi

http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html

Answer (score 16):

#### Yes

When Queen Amidala decides to return to Naboo, Palpatine tells her not to because she'll be forced to sign a treaty with the Trade Federation:

> Go back!! But, Your Majesty, be realistic! You would be in
> danger. **They will force you to sign the treaty.**

Source: the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) and [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120915/quotes).

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit of a subtle distinction, but in [ANH](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) when Han Solo says...

> "Kid, I've flown from one side of this galaxy to the other. I've seen
>   a lot of strange stuff, but I've never seen anything to make me
>   believe there's one all-powerful force controlling everything. There's
>   no mystical energy field that controls my destiny."

...he's not referring to the **F**orce (note the capital F) but a **f**orce (no capitalisation).

Comment: Do you have any backing for that? It seems to me that either meaning is interchangeable. Especially as, from memory, this is in response to Luke's question "You don't believe in the force, do you?"

Comment: @Shadow - Ah, and this is why it's worth reading the scripts. Luke's question is "You don't believe in the Force, do you?". Note the intentional capital F